# Edit Default Report - MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm trying to edit the default report template. I know that you're supposed to call it Normal, and I have that working (can edit the default header background, for example). But when I try and change the Title or add an image to the report (company logo), neither of these changes seem to save. Does anyone have any experience with this?

access 2010, if that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new report, access creates a duplicate of the "Normal" report. However, if later, you make changes to "Normal", this affects only new reports. Reports that you had created previously will not be altered by that.

---

**EDIT**:

I did some research.

Microsoft says in [About using a template to create a form or report](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-using-a-template-to-create-a-form-or-report-HP005187343.aspx),

"The template determines which sections a form or report will have and defines each section's dimensions. The template also contains all the default property settings for the form or report and its sections and controls [...]. However, a template doesn't create controls on a new form or report.

I think this answers your question. It is not a bug, it is by design.

Comment: Right. But when I edit the Normal report, and go to create a new report from the new version, the title defaults to the previous title and the image disappears

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to delete the controls? I have found a way to add an image (embed it into the normal form) but hiding or deleting the default report logo results with the logo reappearing. Do you know if there's a way to fix this? I haven't been able to find any documentation on it.